# How do you fix/hide cosmetic cracks that keep reappearing/disappearing?

Tags: repair, walls, cracks

The home (built in 1962) has cosmetic cracks that keep reappearing/disappearing, like an accordion that squeezes in and out.  Have already tried several methods to fix it, but none have worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is on the wall - drywall, plaster, other?

Comment: Some pictures would help. Add them to your post by clicking [Edit], then just drag n drop the pics in. The site will upload & host them for you

Comment: Where in the world are you? I’ve seen cracks appear but not disappear are they getting wider then narrower? Is it teaching with the seasons, hot/cold or dry/ humid?